# Randomize SimpleXML object results

Tags: php, xml

I want to randomize x (depending on $max) results below. Now the list is presented in order of the XML file the code is pointing to ($string). Any ideas?

```
<?php

    $xml_feed = simplexml_load_string($string);

    global $xml_global_f;
    $xml_global_f = $xml_feed;

    foreach($xml_global_f->reviewDetails->reviewDetail as $val)

        {
        if ($count < $max)
            {
?>
            <li><p><i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-flip-horizontal fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span itemprop="review" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
                <span itemprop="name"><strong><?php
            echo $val->user; ?></strong></span><br /><br>
                <span itemprop="reviewBody"> <?php
            echo $val->text; ?></span>
           <span content="<?php
            echo $val->user; ?>" itemprop="author"></span><span content="<?php
            echo $global_fcs_bn; ?>" itemprop="itemReviewed"></span></p></li>
           <?php
            }

        $count++;
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xml does not have a lot of items, then you can sort them in memory by using a second array and the php function shuffle:

```
<?php

$xml_feed = simplexml_load_string($string);

global $xml_global_f;
$xml_global_f = $xml_feed;

foreach($xml_global_f->reviewDetails->reviewDetail as $val)
    $array[]= $val;

shuffle($array);

foreach($array as $val)

    {
    if ($count < $max)
        {
?>
        <li><p><i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-flip-horizontal fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span itemprop="review" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
            <span itemprop="name"><strong><?php
        echo $val->user; ?></strong></span><br /><br>
            <span itemprop="reviewBody"> <?php
        echo $val->text; ?></span>
       <span content="<?php
        echo $val->user; ?>" itemprop="author"></span><span content="<?php
        echo $global_fcs_bn; ?>" itemprop="itemReviewed"></span></p></li>
       <?php
        }

    $count++;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo! That helped!

Comment: Should there be `{` and `}` after `foreach($xml_global_f->reviewDetails->reviewDetail as $val)` so `$array[]= $val;}`