# PHP Output my XML feed in a random order

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have my XML output working fine but it's in latest date order.  What would be cool is if I could get it in a random order.  I've tried using `shuffle` and I just can't get it working (nothing seems to happen).

Here's an example of the code I'm using to build my XML.  The output is HTML with PHP to insert variables.

```
    // Build the Feed
    $feed   = "http://www.reviewswebsite.com/api/consumer-reviews/?username=" . $userName . "&format=xml&reviews_per_page=20&page=" . $pageNumber;
    $xml    = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfForLoops; $i++)
    {
        $reviewer_name                = $xml->reviews->review[$i]->reviewer_name;
        $date_of_work                 = date('l, d m Y' , strtotime($xml->reviews->review[$i]->date_of_work));
        $average_reviewer_rating      = (float)$xml->reviews->review[$i]->average_rating;
    ..
    ?>
    <div><?php  echo $reviewer_name; ?></div>
...

        <?php ;} ?>
```

Comment: There is no `shuffle` in this code. Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044227/randomize-simplexml-object-results) can help you.

Comment: Yes!  That worked!  Legend, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@The Fourth Bird helped me by passing this link: [Randomize SimpleXML object results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044227/randomize-simplexml-object-results)

The end result I created for **Trust-A-Trader** reviews which I built into a **Joomla! module** was.  I'll try to release the module for free on the Joomla! Extensions Directory (JED).

End code was

```
$feed = "http://www.trustatrader.com/api/consumer-reviews/?username=" . $userName . "&format=xml&reviews_per_page=20&page=" . $pageNumber;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    // Count Reviews, if total number of reviews is less than the total shown on page set in module then show the lesser amount to avoid an error.
    $totalNumberOfReviews = count($xml->reviews->review);
    $numberOfForLoops = $totalNumberOfReviews;
    if ($totalNumberOfReviews > $numberOfReviews) {
        $numberOfForLoops = $numberOfReviews;
    }


    // If the module sets the order to random then shuffle array, or else do in latest first date order.
    if ($params->get('Order') == 0) {
        foreach($xml->reviews->review as $val)
            $array[]= $val;

        shuffle($array);
    }


    // Loop through the reviews and output them.
    foreach($array as $val)
    {
        $i = 0;
        if ($i < $numberOfForLoops)
        {
            ?>
            <div class="mod_trust_a_trader_reviews--review g-grid" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemprop="review" >
                <div class="review g-block size-100" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    <?php echo $val->comments; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="authorBlock g-grid size-100">
                <span class="author g-block size-100" itemprop="author">
                    <?php echo $val->reviewer_name; ?>
                </span>
                </div>
                <div class="score g-block size-100 g-grid">
                    <div class="g-block size-100">
                        <?php starRatingImage($val->average_rating); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g-block size-100 reviewRating">
                        <?php echo '(<span  itemprop="reviewRating">' . $val->average_rating . '</span>)'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        $i++;
    }

?>
```